# org-mode: Bump/increase node priorities in the current buffer

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to automatically bump the priorities of all nodes in the current buffer by 1?

If that's relevant, I use digital priorities(`org-priority-down`/`org-priority-up` work fine).
It's a bit annoying doing it manually each time in a large document.

My use case is - sometimes it is easier to balance priorities this way(e.g. bump all existing ones and add new blockers/higher priority nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-map-entries` is your friend (read its doc string with `C-h f org-map-entries` and also the [Mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html) section of the manual for details).
In this particular case, all you have to do is:

```el
M-: (org-map-entries #'org-priority-up t 'file)
```

If you only want top-level nodes to be bumped, use `"LEVEL=1"` instead of `t` for the `MATCH` argument (i.e. the second argument).

And, of course, you can always wrap this in an Elisp command (a function with an `interactive` specification) and bind it to a key.